# How to create a stock quote fetching app in python

Tags: python, google-finance

I'm quite new to programming in **Python**.

I want to make an application which will **fetch stock prices** from [google finance](http://www.google.com/finance). One example is CSCO *(Cisco Sytems)*. I would then use that data to **warn the user when the stock reaches a certain value**.  It also needs to **refresh every 30 seconds**.

The problem is I dont have a clue how to fetch the data!

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This module comes courtesy of [Corey Goldberg](http://www.goldb.org/goldblog/2007/09/14/PythonStockQuoteModule.aspx).

Program:

```
import urllib
import re

def get_quote(symbol):
    base_url = 'http://finance.google.com/finance?q='
    content = urllib.urlopen(base_url + symbol).read()
    m = re.search('id="ref_694653_l".*?>(.*?)<', content)
    if m:
        quote = m.group(1)
    else:
        quote = 'no quote available for: ' + symbol
    return quote
```

Sample Usage:

```
import stockquote
print stockquote.get_quote('goog')
```

**Update**: Changed the regular expression to match Google Finance's latest format (as of 23-Feb-2011). This demonstrates the main issue when relying upon screen scraping.

Comment: Simply copy-pasted this code. But output says `no quote available for: goog`.

Comment: Thanks Dharmit. I hadn't used this code in awhile, but you are right - Google Finance has a new output format. I've updated the code and it should now work.

Comment: @Mysticmonk Google is blocking access to queries by this type of script

Answer (score 13):

As for now (2015), the google finance api is deprecated. But you may use the pypi module [googlefinance](https://pypi.org/project/googlefinance/).

Install googlefinance

```
$pip install googlefinance
```

It is easy to get current stock price:

```
>>> from googlefinance import getQuotes
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(getQuotes('AAPL'), indent=2)
[
  {
    "Index": "NASDAQ", 
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "129.09", 
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2015-03-02T16:04:29Z", 
    "LastTradePrice": "129.09", 
    "Yield": "1.46", 
    "LastTradeTime": "4:04PM EST", 
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Mar 2, 4:04PM EST", 
    "Dividend": "0.47", 
    "StockSymbol": "AAPL", 
    "ID": "22144"
  }
]
```

Google finance is a source that provides real-time stock data. There are also other APIs from yahoo, such as [yahoo-finance](https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance), but they are delayed by 15min for NYSE and NASDAQ stocks.

Comment: `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` -- is this module toast now?

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib
import re

def get_quote(symbol):
    base_url = 'http://finance.google.com/finance?q='
    content = urllib.urlopen(base_url + symbol).read()
    m = re.search('id="ref_(.*?)">(.*?)<', content)
    if m:
        quote = m.group(2)
    else:
        quote = 'no quote available for: ' + symbol
    return quote
```

I find that if you use ref_(.*?) and use m.group(2) you will get a better result as the reference id changes from stock to stock.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the HTMLParser to get the value of the meta tags google places in it's html

```
<meta itemprop="name"
        content="Cerner Corporation" />
<meta itemprop="url"
        content="https://www.google.com/finance?cid=92421" />
<meta itemprop="imageUrl"
        content="https://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=g&q=NASDAQ:CERN&tkr=1&p=1d&enddatetime=2014-04-09T12:47:31Z" />
<meta itemprop="tickerSymbol"
        content="CERN" />
<meta itemprop="exchange"
        content="NASDAQ" />
<meta itemprop="exchangeTimezone"
        content="America/New_York" />
<meta itemprop="price"
        content="54.66" />
<meta itemprop="priceChange"
        content="+0.36" />
<meta itemprop="priceChangePercent"
        content="0.66" />
<meta itemprop="quoteTime"
        content="2014-04-09T12:47:31Z" />
<meta itemprop="dataSource"
        content="NASDAQ real-time data" />
<meta itemprop="dataSourceDisclaimerUrl"
        content="//www.google.com/help/stock_disclaimer.html#realtime" />
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency"
        content="USD" />
```

With code like this:

```
import urllib
try:
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
except:
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class QuoteData:
    pass

class GoogleFinanceParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.quote = QuoteData()
        self.quote.price = -1

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "meta":
            last_itemprop = ""
            for attr, value in attrs:
                if attr == "itemprop":
                    last_itemprop = value

                if attr == "content" and last_itemprop == "name":
                    self.quote.name = value
                if attr == "content" and last_itemprop == "price":
                    self.quote.price = value
                if attr == "content" and last_itemprop == "priceCurrency":
                    self.quote.priceCurrency = value
                if attr == "content" and last_itemprop == "priceChange":
                    self.quote.priceChange = value
                if attr == "content" and last_itemprop == "priceChangePercent":
                    self.quote.priceChangePercent = value
                if attr == "content" and last_itemprop == "quoteTime":
                    self.quote.quoteTime = value
                if attr == "content" and last_itemprop == "exchange":
                    self.quote.exchange = value
                if attr == "content" and last_itemprop == "exchangeTimezone":
                    self.quote.exchangeTimezone = value


def getquote(symbol):
    url = "http://finance.google.com/finance?q=%s" % symbol
    content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

    gfp = GoogleFinanceParser()
    gfp.feed(content)
    return gfp.quote;


quote = getquote('CSCO')
print quote.name, quote.price
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to pull data from Yahoo... Here is a simple function. This does not scrape data off a normal page. I thought I had a link to the page describing this in the comments, but I do not see it now - there is a magic string appended to the URL to request specific fields.

```
import urllib as u
import string
symbols = 'amd ibm gm kft'.split()

def get_data():
    data = []
    url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s='
    for s in symbols:
        url += s+"+"
    url = url[0:-1]
    url += "&f=sb3b2l1l"
    f = u.urlopen(url,proxies = {})
    rows = f.readlines()
    for r in rows:
        values = [x for x in r.split(',')]
        symbol = values[0][1:-1]
        bid = string.atof(values[1])
        ask = string.atof(values[2])
        last = string.atof(values[3])
        data.append([symbol,bid,ask,last,values[4]])
    return data
```

Here, I found the link that describes the magic string:
http://cliffngan.net/a/13

Comment: There is also a Yahoo data fetcher built in to the Python Pandas library ([link](http://www.statalgo.com/2011/09/08/pandas-getting-financial-data-from-yahoo-fred-etc/)) (and Federal Reserve and Fama/French data libraried too). The current specifications may become deprecated in favor of a more robust data query system, but I think Pandas is the way to go for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html
for fetching arbitrary URLs.

Apart from that you should better look a some web service providing the data in JSON format.

Otherwise you have to implement parsing etc. on your own.

Screenscrapping yahoo.com for getting the stocks is unlikely the right road to success.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking at the [Google Finance APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/), although I don't see a Python API or wrapper.  It looks like the only options for accessing the data directly are Java and JavaScript.  You can also [use cURL](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/using_cURL.html) if you're familiar with it and it's available on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Another good place to start is Google Finance's own API: http://code.google.com/apis/finance/  You can look at their [finance gadgets](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/finance-gadgets.html) for some example code.

Comment: Just to save you a click, 'the Google Finance APIs are no longer available'.