# Google finance scraper return

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping, finance, stock

I'm pretty new to python and programming in general. I'm currently working on a script to scrape stock quotes from Google finance. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request as ur
import re

def getquote(symbol):
    base_url = 'http://finance.google.com/finance?q='
    content = ur.urlopen(base_url + symbol).read()
    m = re.search(b'id="ref_(.*?)">(.*?)<', content)
    if m:
        quote = m.group(2)
    else:
        quote = 'no quote available for: ' + symbol
    return quote
```

which returns:

```
b'655.65'
```

(655.65 is the current price of Google stock which is the symbol I passed in)

My question is: is there a way for me to either scrub the return so I just get the price without the b or the quotations? Ideally I'd like to have it returned as a float but if need be I can have it return as a string and convert it to a float when I need it later.

I've referenced these other posts:

[How to create a stock quote fetching app in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081710/how-to-create-a-stock-quote-fetching-app-in-python)

[Python TypeError on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184483/python-typeerror-on-regex)

[How to convert between bytes and strings in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010551/how-to-convert-between-bytes-and-strings-in-python-3)

[Convert bytes to a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string)

Perhaps I've missed something in one of those but I believe I've tried everything I could find and it is still returning in the format shown above.

*SOLVED*
The problem I was having wasn't displaying a string without quotes, it was that I had a value set to a byte literal that needed to first be converted to a string literal and then to a float. I had tried this but I tried this outside of the if statement (noob move). the solution was as v1k45 suggested:
add a line in the if statement
    quote = float(quote.decode('utf-8'))
to decode it and convert to float.

thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python return without " ' "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482649/python-return-without)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line in the `if` condition:

```
        quote = float(quote.decode('utf-8'))
```

You have to decode the bytes to unicode to return a proper string. Use float() to convert it into a float.

Comment: That took care of it! thanks!
I knew how to convert to float, and I had tried decoding it but I was doing it outside the if statement which now makes sense as to why it wasn't working lol.

Comment: this is why i prefer 2.7 over 3 for doing dirty jobs :D