# Search stock symbol in google finance

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm trying to verify stock ticker through google finance. For example: when I type in "IBEX", I'm expecting Google finance comes back with the second choice not the first one. How can I archive this?

```
ticker = 'IBEX'    
url="https://www.google.com/finance?q={}".format(ticker)
```

[image: Searching stock ticker in google finance]

[image: Default result, not expected]

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 2):

The correct ticker is `LON:IBEX`, which you need to `urlencode` to `LON%3AIBEX`

Related: [How to create a stock quote fetching app in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081710/how-to-create-a-stock-quote-fetching-app-in-python)

Comment: LON:IBEX is the final result I will parse from html. Now the problem is: google try to match my input with name or ticker. I only want google to match it with ticker.

Comment: You can parse that "third" column, right? Something like `col3 + ":" + col1`?

Comment: I can't fix Google search for you, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This issue eventually is solved by using selenium. Both Firefox driver and PhantomJS work very well. With selenium, I don't need to worry about Google's limitation either on how many requests you can submit in short term.