# Creating a demo stock portfolio and test performance?

Tags: python, stock, portfolio

Is there a tool to create a demo portfolio and check performance for given dates?

e.g.
input symbols: fb, amzn, hbi, etc...
input dates: 1.1.12 - 1.6.17
output: report of revenue per stock, of whole portfolio, std, max loss at time period etc...

Is there a blackbox that do that? do you know of any libraries?

I know it's possible to do so with python (pandas numpy) and some stocks api's (alpha vantage, yahoo, qundle etc..).

thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081710/how-to-create-a-stock-quote-fetching-app-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[googlefinance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlefinance)

[yahoo-finance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance)

[realtie-stock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/realtime-stock/1.0.0)

Comment: I have read about them. did not see an option to create a portfolio and check for PAST performance given start and end dates. Do you know that they give this kind of service or do you assume?